# Column manipulation, merge some

Tags: r, bash

I have a tab delimited file with 4 columns. I would like to replace the tabs between column 1 and 2 with a comma, but leave the tab between 2 and 3 untouched. Then I want to replace the tab between 3 and 4 with a comma.

Is there a way to do easily do this in R or bash?

Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 4):

In bash with awk:

```
awk '{print $1","$2"\t"$3","$4}' ./file.txt > result.txt
```

or with R:

```
> d <- readLines("./file.txt")
> d <- gsub("\\t([^\\t]+\\t?)", ",\\1", d, perl=TRUE)
> writeLines(d, "./result.txt", "\n", FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dat = read.table('tab.txt', sep="\t")
dat1 = data.frame(paste0(dat[,2],", ", dat[,3]), paste0(dat[,3],", ", dat[,4]))


Where tab.txt:

            A   B   C   D
1   Title   Author  Condition   Binding
2   Pride and Prejudice Jane Austen used    softcover
3   The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn  Mark Twain  new hardcover
4   The Art of War  Sun Tzu used    hardcover
```

Source:https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63377?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

```
> gsub("(.+)(\\\t)(.+\\\t.+)(\\\t)(.+$)", "\\1,\\3,\\5", "ab\tdc\tef\tgh")
[1] "ab,dc\tef,gh"
```

So do that on the result of:

```
 dat <- readLines(file="filnam.tsv")
```

Comment: I don't think you need to escape `\t` - e.g. `sub("^(.+?)\t(.+?)\t(.+?)\t(.+?)$","\\1,\\2\t\\3,\\4","ab\tdc\tef\tgh")`